# C# MessageBox not working

Tags: c#

I've been working on this for a project and the messagebox not showing
Could someone please help me?

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MaterialSkin.Controls;
using MaterialSkin.Animations;
using MaterialSkin;
using System.Web;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Windows;

namespace Liquid_Reborn
{
    public partial class Login : MaterialForm
    {
        public Login()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var materialSkinManager = MaterialSkinManager.Instance;
            materialSkinManager.AddFormToManage(this);
            materialSkinManager.Theme = MaterialSkinManager.Themes.LIGHT;
            materialSkinManager.ColorScheme = new ColorScheme(Primary.LightBlue200, Primary.LightBlue300, Primary.LightBlue300, Accent.LightBlue200, TextShade.WHITE);

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string cpuInfo = string.Empty;
            ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("win32_processor");
            ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
            foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
            {
                if (cpuInfo == "")
                {
                    //Get only the first CPU's ID
                    cpuInfo = mo.Properties["processorID"].Value.ToString();
                    break;
                }
                var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cpuInfo);
                String hwid = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                Stream stream = client.OpenRead("http://techshow.us/liquid/hwid.txt/");
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                String content = reader.ReadToEnd();
                if (content.Contains(hwid))
                {

                }
                MessageBox.Show("ok");

            }
        }
    }
}
```

why doesnt the messagebox display?
ive tried most things and none work
Nothing happens the ui just shows and idk what to do\
please help me i need this for my project

Comment: The collection `moc` may be empty thats why the loop doesn't execute

Comment: What do you mean? the code is out of the collection

Comment: Did you put a debug point on the line to check if this is being executed?

Comment: add a breakpoint at the starting point of your `Form1_Load` event, and check the code step-by-step to see where does the control flows and what are the values of your variables.

Comment: Tejsoft how would I do that?

Comment: How do I check if it executes?

Comment: Add the `MessageBox.Show("ok");` call at the first line of the form load and see what happens. If it pop ups the `moc` collection is empty as @shahsani says.

Comment: There are many videos in youtube showing how to debug source code in visual studio. You should view them. Also check this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/dn986851.aspx a

Comment: You may have only one (or zero) object in the `moc` collection, in which case that line will not be executed (obviously if there are zero items, none of the code in that block will execute, but if there is one item, you have a `break;` statement which will exit the block for that iteration).

Comment: My brackets were off by a bit but thanks for your responses

Comment: You cannot deface your post once you get an answer.  Read [ask] and take the [tour] and maybe the licensing terms

Answer (score 1):

`if (cpuInfo == "")` will always be true because the value doesn't change after initializing. The loop breaks before the MessageBox code is reached.

Remove `break;` to allow the code to continue, or

Use `continue;` instead to skip to the next value in the loop.